# Copy matching lines to the next line and modify?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Given a file like this:

```
a foo 1
b bar 2
c foo 3
d baz 4
e bar 5
```

I want to modify that file as follows: copy every line containing `bar` to the following line and change `bar` to `bar2`, so that the result is like this:

```
a foo 1
b bar 2
b bar2 2
c foo 3
d baz 4
e bar 5
e bar2 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Stéphane suggests, just `p`rint the line and then `s`ubstitute, `sed` will autoprint the result:

```
sed '/bar/{p;s//&2/;}'  infile
```

Comment: Why not just `sed '/bar/{p;s//&2/;}'` or `sed -n 'p;s/bar/&2/p'` ?

Comment: @Stéphane - :) that's the kind of question that's really hard to answer... I'll blame it on my childhood adhd

Comment: On further research, looks like the substitution part could be more generally written as `s/foo/foo2/`, so `foo2` could be anything (instead of "same thing but append a 2").

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '1; sub(/bar/,"&2")' file
a foo 1
b bar 2
b bar2 2
c foo 3
d baz 4
e bar 5
e bar2 5
```

```
$ awk '1; sub(/bar/,"hello world")' file
a foo 1
b bar 2
b hello world 2
c foo 3
d baz 4
e bar 5
e hello world 5
```

print the line ([`1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24643330/1745001)) then try to replace `bar` with whatever you like and if that succeeds (`sub()` returns non-zero) print the now-modified line again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/bar/{print; sub(/bar/,"&2")}1'
```

As [the `sed` answer suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762787/469418), the `awk` command `print`s the record with pattern `bar` and then `sub`stitutes it with `bar2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.put; .put if s/bar/bar2/;'  file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne '.put; .subst(/bar/, "bar2").put if /bar/;'   file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne '.put; /bar/ && .subst(/bar/, "bar2").put;'   file
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl-family. It features high-level support for Unicode built-in. Above, the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags are used, which loads the data linewise into `$_`, Raku (and Perl's) topic-variable. Because Raku auto-chomps lines by default, calling `put` (instead of `print`) adds a newline back for you (imagine `put` stands for ***p**rint-**u**sing-**t**erminator*).

- Raku reduces ambiguity by requiring that `put`/`print` etc. be given an explicit object. Thus `.put` is short for `$_.put` which is the same as `put $_`, meaning the unmodified line will be printed.
- In the first example the modified line is added with the well-known `s///` substitution notation. (Use `s:g///` here for global replacement).
- In the second example, `if` the match is found the `subst` will occur and the resultant line will be out`put` on the next line. The third example is almost identical to the second except it relies on `&&` short-circuiting.
- When a match occurs in Raku, generally the match loads into the `$<>` variable (identical to `$/`, but easier to read). So the task of *"adding a 2"* can be more simply accomplished with `S/bar/$<>2/` or `.subst(/bar/, "$<>2");`.

Sample Input:

```
a foo 1
b bar 2
c foo 3
d baz 4
e bar 5
```

Sample Output:

```
a foo 1
b bar 2
b bar2 2
c foo 3
d baz 4
e bar 5
e bar2 5
```

---

If you have a particularly complex Regex that you're using, the above examples aren't that DRY. But you can save a match into a temporary variable for further use (e.g. `$a` below):

```
~$ raku -ne '.put; if m/complicated_pattern/ -> $a {S/<$a>/replacement/.put};'  file
```

OR declare a `regex`-class variable from the start:

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my regex RE {complicated_pattern};  \
             .put; .put if s/<RE>/replacement/;  file

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my regex RE {complicated_pattern};  \
             .put; .subst(/<RE>/, "replacement" ).put if /<RE>/;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my regex RE {complicated_pattern};  \
             .put; /<RE>/ && put .subst(/<RE>/, "replacement" );'  file
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Regex
https://raku.org